# Continue downloading with NSURLSession, even after the app is killed

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios7, download, nsurlconnection

I am aware that with NSURLSession, data download continues even after we put the application in the background. However, I am not sure that if a app is killed, the download would continue or not.

Is it possible at all? In case YES, could you tell me step-by-step approach?

Thanks in advance.

Anupam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your app is killed, nothing happens. No code is executed. The only time you can start a download progress is with background fetch and that only happens at times determined by the OS.